# Why "wait" should not be called when multiple locks are held?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

```
  public synchronized void methodOne(List<String> profileNames, ParameterAttributes parameterAttributes) throws InterruptedException {

    if (profileNames != null && !profileNames.isEmpty()) {
      profileNames.forEach(profileName -> System.out.println(profileName));
    }
    synchronized(lockObj) {
      lockObj.wait();
    }
  }
```

Here we have synchronized method and inside the method again I have synchronized block which is calling the wait method.

Comment: Please add some "meat" (explanatory text and an actual textual *question*) to your "bones" (unexplained code post).

Comment: You acquire the lock and then you wait and don't do anything. You can just use a real life example: There is a door that several people want to open and one key for it. Now someone comes, takes the key and sits down in the sun, never doing anything with the key. That's not very polite now, is it?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, no thread in your program should ever keep a mutex locked for any longer than it takes to update a few variables (like, no more than a microsecond if its running on a modern, workstation or server). If you keep any mutex locked for longer than that, then there probably is a better way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, while your thread is waiting to be notified it still holds the other locks significantly increasing the chances of a deadlock.

It looks like your code owns three object monitors:

- the object that methodOne belongs to because it is synchronized
- the lockObj because you are synchronizing on it
- parameterAttributes because you are calling wait on it

Does your code throw an IllegalMonitorStateException? I ask because it is not apparent in the code example that it does actually own parameterAttributes's monitor (there is no synchronized(parameterAttributes) in the code example).

Anyway, I think you need to simplify. Owning so many monitors seems overly complex. Usually you only need on strategy, synchronized methods or a lockObj that protects some mutable state, not both. Also, I'd suggest looking into an actor framework like Akka.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a local copy of the `profileNames`, and then release the lock before doing any I/O:

```
public void methodOne(
    List<String> profileNames, 
    ParameterAttributes parameterAttributes
) throws InterruptedException 
{
    if (profileNames != null && !profileNames.isEmpty()) {
        List<String> localNames;

        synchronized (this) {
            localNames = new ArrayList<>(profileNames);
        }
        localNames.forEach(profileName -> System.out.println(profileName));
    }

    synchronized(lockObj) {
        parameterAttributes.wait();  //NOTE: Wrong way to use wait(), but that's a topic
    }                                //      for another question.
}
```

Sometimes you have to change your ideas about what is efficient and what is inefficient when you write multi-threaded code for multi-processor platforms.  In single-threaded code, it would be inefficient to copy the list, but the performance improvement you might get by releasing the lock before you do your I/O could be much greater than the hit that you take by making the copy.